# change the background color of comments in darkmode

Tags: widget, comments, telegram, blogs, darkmode

In my blog ([4AllFreeModApks.blogspot.com](https://4AllFreeModApks.blogspot.com)), I can not change the comment section background color to dark in darkmode
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7C3C.png)

need to change comment section also to dark in darkmode

i used comments.app (telegram widget)

is it possible to overide external css with inline css

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.